# jqueryui dialog event: how to attach an even only once

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

JqueryUI:
The code below fires an alert every time the box is closed, but how can I make it so it only does this for once and not every time.

```
$("#box").dialog({
    close: function () {
            alert(999);
    }
});
```

This was how I did it before using jQueryUi:

```
$("#box").one("click", function () {
    alert(999);
    return false
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-close), the `.close()` method also has a corresponding event: `dialogclose`.  So you should be able to do this:

```
$("#box").one("dialogclose",function() {
    alert(999);
});
```